# Gradle: verify list of classes are in classpath on build

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, classpath

I have a multi-project build that contains dozens of XML files and my issue is that you specify in certain XML files a full Class Name (E.g. `com.myproject.CheckItem`) but there is no check at any point to verify that what you typed is correct during the build process. You can only see if what you typed is correct by going to the area of the app that utilizes the XML to see if it works or not.

What I would like to do is that at some point during the gradle build verify that the Class Names defined in these XML files are either one of my Classes or in one of the jars I have in a two lib folders added as compile dependencies.

Where I am at right now is I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` that has all the keys being the Class Names and the value being a list of files that contain the key.

So, it looks like this:

```
com.myproject.CheckItem
  - C:\Development\my-app\app-core\src\main\resources\META-INF\Totally.xml
  - C:\Development\my-app\app-filter\src\main\resources\META-INF\Awesome.xml

com.myproject.CheckSquare
  - C:\Development\my-app\app-core\src\main\resources\META-INF\FarOut.xml
```

I've been fiddling around all night looking at the best way to go about this, and the easiest would be to do something like this:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.myproject.CheckItem", false, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    // it exists on the classpath
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // it does not exist on the classpath
}
```

However I haven't had luck on integrating this into the Gradle build process which is where I'd like it, ideally spun off intp my own Gradle Plugin.

As an alternative I've thought about doing a parameterized unit test that does this since within the unit test it will have access to the classpath easily and I could do the above but would prefer doing it within the Gradle build process.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I solved by JavaExec task. The general idea is: code your java in utility project,  run it from gradle with your main project dependencies and compiled classes on classpath, profit.

In my case, I was inspecting a package for  Hibernate annotations, and then generating schema to an output file. I found a solution for maven: http://blog.iprofs.nl/2013/01/29/hibernate4-schema-generation-ddl-from-annotated-entities/ and tweaked it to fit my needs.

In my gradle build (use as example):

```
task (generateSchema, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec){
    main = 'nl.iprofs.examples.util.SchemaGenerator'
    classpath = files('./hibernate-schema-generator-1.0.jar',configurations.compile, sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    args 'my.package.entities'
    args 'src/main/resources/'
    args 'TSQL'
}

build.dependsOn generateSchema
```

In your case you'd want to pass your xml names as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up structuring my Gradle project as a multi-project Gradle build and ended up creating a `build-test` project that had as compile dependencies all the required sub projects and global dependencies.

Then I created the parametrized junit test that did the classpath check, this way I can:

1. Choose to skip the test
2. View a detailed html report of what is incorrect vs checking a build log

This was simpler than doing something like enlait suggested.